# how to set white color to any letter in TextView except numbers and commas in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I want to  set white color to any letter in TextView except numbers and commas 
and Then I  want to set the color of other charactors to White .
How can I do it ?

*Example*

```
19,319,931 coins
//19,319,931 should has yellow color.
//coins should has has white color
```

Comment: You can try SpannableStringBuilder for this :  https://medium.com/@programmerr47/working-with-spans-in-android-ca4ab1327bc4

Comment: Try this too https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/11274467

Comment: There is way for do it with `SpannableStringBuilder`  and [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Spannable TextView**

A **spannable TextView** can be used in Android to highlight a particular portion of text with a different color, style, size, and/or click event in a single TextView widget.

**So Try this :**

```
    String coinText = txtDiamonds.getText().toString();
    char currentChar;
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(coinText);
    ForegroundColorSpan color;
    for (int i = 0; i < coinText.length(); i++) {
        currentChar = coinText.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(currentChar) || ((int) currentChar) == ((int) ','))
            color = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
        else
            color = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE);
        spannable.setSpan(color, i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    txtDiamonds.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Regular expressions as follows

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(myTextView.getText().toString());
// Matching non-digits
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\D+").matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

// Matching digits followed by "," 0 or 1 time
matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+,?").matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

myTextView.setText(spannable);
```